# Lenovo W500 keyboards locks when connecting to external screen

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, windows-server-2008, external-display

I have a Lenovo W500, which has dual boot.

When I boot into Windows 2008 R2 and connect to an external screen or projector, the keyboard locks. Sometimes it is just a few of the keys, sometimes keys start different programs.

I do not have this problem if I boot with windows 7. I have run windows update, but it did not help.

Comment: I can only say the usual stuff. Windows Server is not a supported operating system. Its for...servers. If you need some functions, use VMWare. Why do you use it in the first place?

Comment: @Shiki, We use it to develop SharePoint applications, we would have less memory available if we used VMWare

Comment: Hmm VMWare can assign about 16gb ram per guest and W500 supports 8gb memory as far as I know. | (Okay I know you want to use Win Server but sorry I don't know a way. Maybe you can try installing Lenovo System Update + the drivers from Lenovo, maybe they will install without a problem (the Windows 7 drivers that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a longshot, but I wonder if you're having a problem with a stuck modifier key, somehow triggered by the display switch.  When the keyboard 'locks', `press & release each of the modifier keys once (windows key and both sets of shift/ctrl/alt keys) to make sure none of your modifiers are stuck.

If one of the modifiers is stuck typing normal keystrokes will lead to unintended results.  For example: typing 'w' with the control key stuck become 'CTRL-W' (close window) or  'enter' becomes 'ALT+ENTER' (open properties), etc.

Comment: Thanks, ended up fixing this by getting a new machine :)